# how to use backbone noconflict in typescript?

Tags: typescript, backbone.js, module, namespaces

I have a typescript file which directly used Backbone. But I want to change it use own version of Backbone.

```
export var ownBackbone :typeof Backbone = Backbone.noConflict();

export class UserContainerView extends ownBackbone.View<UserContainerContainerModel> {
    public currentView;
    public hasChanges;
    collection: ownBackbone.Collection<UserContainerContainerModel>;
    constructor(options: any) {
        super();
        this.collection = options.collection;
        this.$el = options.el; 
    }

    initialize(options: any) {
    }

    close() {
    }
```

}

it throwing error at Build cant find name ownBackbone

Answer (score 0):

The above code seems to be working in upgraded version of typescript that i was working i.e 2.3.Only small modification has to be done instaed of

collection: ownBackbone.Collection;

we have to use
collection: Backbone.Collection;

The reason is we cant access type through variable